# Samba3 GPO Alternative

Tags: group-policy, samba

Samba4 isn't ready for production so I'm stuck with Samba3 but I want GPOs for my Windows 7 clients.
Is there a way to implement GPOs or something like it using Samba3 without resorting to manually creating login scripts to set [registry settings](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25250)? I'm guessing using the login scripts is the only way but is there software to automate creating them?

Comment: Presumably using AD doesn't cut it for you?

Answer (score 4):

GPOs aren't possible with Samba 3 - they require directory services.

Samba 4 is used in production by quite a few people; it's stable, but it lacks some of the features that Samba 3 has, such as printing support (you can run a separate domain member with Samba 3 on it and a printer though), and it doesn't do DC to DC replication well yet.

Comment: I know GPOs aren't possible on Samba3, I'm asking for an alternative which can achieve the same results.

Comment: Only group policies can replace group policies, but there are some alternatives that provide a subset of their functionality.  Which group policy features do you need?

Comment: Enforce workstation user/machine restrictions mostly but Desktop shortcuts, local files, browser settings, global proxy settings, software deployment (Although, that can done with the script easily anyway) and Default User Profile for new users.

Answer (score 1):

The **only** thing I can find.
http://www.nitrobit.com/grouppolicy.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat.. (my appliance, zentyal, does not yet have a version with Samba 4..) this is the closest I can find, but have not tried it yet. http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Implementing_System_Policies_with_Samba